# Highcharts showing December instead of November in x-axis

Tags: highcharts

Why is highcharts showing december instead of november in my x-axis?

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2014,11,15,19,0)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyLypgb4/)

Comment: If [roywasse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3122869/roywasse)'s answer solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTC starts at 0 (0=January ... 11=December)

So, the code should be:

```js
pointStart: Date.UTC(2014,10,15,19,0)
```

Comment: @roywasse It would improve the strength of this answer if you could source this.

Comment: What can i use instead of Date.UTC()? Is it possible to do something like this `pointStart: Date.X(2014,11,15,19,0)` ?

Comment: Is it possible to limit the right y-axis to 100% ? I have set min:0 and max:100 but it doesnt works. Thank you!

Comment: Check out the JavaScript date object. There no support for specific timezones etc through a method. Also, new questions on stack overflow should be listed separately (I don't have the answer to the question concerning the y axis)